# Что за странный ответ ajax-а формата json

Tags: ajax, php

ajax-ом возвращаю json формат (там массив). Возвращаются все данные, но в таком виде:
на сервере:

```
function commentsString($data) {
    foreach($data as $w) {
        $string .= commentsToTemplate($w);
    }
    return $string;
}
```

В $string заносится html-код (комментариев) которые формируются динамически функцией.
В firebag видим:

```
/* сюда поместился html-код, кот. должен находиться внутри массива первым элементом */ ["",8]
```

Восьмёрка на своём месте. Причём, если в $string вручную занести код, то всё нормально.

Т.е.:

```
$string = "<p>текст...</p><p>текст...</p>";
echo json_encode(array($string, $cnt));
```

Получаем:

```
["<p>текст...</p><p>текст...</p>",8]
```

Сама функция преобразующая массив данных в комментарии:

```
// ШАБЛОН КОММЕНТАРИЕВ
function commentsToTemplate($tmpCom, $ff){
    $string = '<li id="'.$tmpCom['id'].'"';
    if($tmpCom['parent_id'] != 0) $string .= ' class="otvets"';
    $string .= '>
    <div class="avatar">
        <a href="?user='.$tmpCom['id_user'].'">
        <img src="'.$GLOBALS['host'].photoput($tmpCom['first_photo'], $tmpCom['id_user']).'" alt="" title="Перейти на страницу '.$tmpCom['imya'].'" class="img"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="coment_info">
        <span class="tip"></span>
        <p class="font_small f-gray right">'.modifier_data($tmpCom['date'],1).'</p>
        <p><a href="?user='.$tmpCom['id_user'].'" title="Перейти на страницу пользователя" target="_blank">'.$tmpCom['imya'].' '.$tmpCom['fameli'].' </a>'.online($tmpCom['id_user'], $tmpCom['online']);
        $string .= '</p>
        <p class="coment_message">'.$tmpCom['text'].'</p>
        <p>&nbsp;
            <span class="font_small non parent right f-gray">';
                $string .= ($_SESSION["user"]["id_user"]) ? '<a href="'.$tmpCom['id_user'].'" class="linkRed modalMsg" func="22" title="Пожаловаться администратору">Спам</a>' : 'Спам';
                if ($_SESSION["user"]["id_user"] && $tmpCom['id_user'] == $_SESSION["user"]["id_user"]) $string .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="'.$tmpCom['id'].'" class="linkRed modalMsg cornCom" func="'.$ff.'" title="Удалить запись со стены">Удалить</a>';
            $string .= '</span>';
            if($tmpCom['parent_id'] == 0) $string .= '<span class="font_small non left"><span class="spr s42">&nbsp;</span> <a href="#" class="linkGreen otv">ответить</a></span>';
            $string .= '
        </p>
    </div>
    </li>'; 
    if($tmpCom["childs"]) {
        $string .= commentsString($tmpCom["childs"], $ff);
        $string .= '<li>Ответов: '.$tmpCom["subcomment_count"].'</li>';
    }
    return $string;
}
```

Comment: а в какой функции у вас    echo json_encode(array($string, $cnt)); ?

Comment: Если я правильно понял: __json_encode(array($string, $cnt));__
находится на стороне сервера. Она возвращает ajax-у массив.

Comment: Ну так у Вас беда явно или **$data** - или **commentsToTemplate($w)** **пустое** возвращает. Причём  тут json вообще?

Comment: Нет, нет. Всё возвращается нормально, отформатированно как надо.  Только результат помешается не в массив, а за его пределы.  
__/* сюда поместился html-код, кот. должен находиться внутри массива первым элементом */ ["",8]__  
как будто написанно: __echo json_encode($string, array("", $cnt));__

Comment: странно, а если, например, echo json_encode(array('string' => $string, 'cnt' => $cnt));

Comment: А попробуйте убрать **echo json_encode($string, array("", $cnt));** - может где завалялось echo html-кода? Потому что json_encode выдаст в обёртке по любому... и если бы была бы магия с переменной $string то было бы аля [ html-cod, ["",8]]

Comment: commentsToTemplate возвращает результат html-код комментариев.  
Если ставить там echo $string. то как раз и получается аля [ html-cod, ["",8]], если return $string, то выдаёт как бы нормально, но начало кода первого коммента:  __{"string":"<li id=\"775\">\r\n\t<div class=\"avatar\">\r\n\t\t<a href=\"?user=1\">\r\n\t\t<img src=\"http:\/\/dnevnik\/user_photo\/1\/mini-1342279648.0.180946001342279648.jpg\" alt=\"\" title=\"","cnt":8}__  
на title всё прерывается.

Comment: А если $string сначала инициализировать?

    function commentsString($data) {
        $string = "";
        foreach($data as $w) {
            $string .= commentsToTemplate($w);
        }
        return $string;
    }

**echo** в функции - точно отменить.

Comment: То же самое. :-( На __title=\"__ прерывается и всё!  
Я вот что наковырял: Вместо всего кода в commentsToTemplate вставляю __$string = $tmpCom['id'].'<br />';__  
Т.е. пробую вывести только id пришедших комментов и ву аля:  
__{"string":"775<br \/>770<br \/>769<br \/>","cnt":8}__
Может для json в функции commentsToTemplate такое соединение строк как __$string .= " ... ";__ не допустимо? Тогда как их правильно склеить?

Comment: Приведите код CommentsToTemplate - явно там собака порылась. Сильно сомневаюсь что json тут причём.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте такой вариант **commentsString**:

```
function commentsString($data) {
    $result = "";
    foreach($data as $w) {
        $result .= commentsToTemplate($w);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

очень мне почему-то кажется что commentsToTemplate тупо затирает $string (оказывается она как то в глобальной области видимости). И по поводу $ff - это вы просто старый вариант не обновили по параметрам?

Comment: Не не получается. Щас буду пробовать работать с commentsToTemplate